# return javascript from an ajax call in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to return some javascript from an ajax response, Everything seems to be ok but still, I'm getting an error. Here's my code:

```
function class_fees_settings(){
    global $wpdb;
    $class_id = $_POST['value'];
    $fees_table = $wpdb->prefix."wpsp_fees_settings";
    $sql_res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $fees_table WHERE cid = '$class_id'");
    foreach ($sql_res as $fee) :  ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#fs-adm").val("'<?php echo $fee->admission_fees; ?>'");
            $("#fs-tution").val("'<?php echo $fee->tution_fees; ?>'");
            $("#fs-trans").val("'<?php echo $fee->$transport_chg; ?>'");
            $("#fs-annual").val("'<?php echo $fee->annual_chg; ?>'");
            $("#fs-recreation").val("'<?php echo $fee->recreation_chg; ?>'");
        </script><?php 
    endforeach;
    wp_die();
}
```

I also tried to assign values to an variable inside loop like `$adm = $fee->admission_fees` and then echoed the `$adm` but this is giving me an error and then I directly echoed the `$fee->admission_fees`, it is working fine.
Also I'm not getting any proper error message in console or page instead getting an error `500 Internal Server error` in chrome Network tab Where all my `XHR`s are listed

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in line no. 10 remove `$` sign before `transport_chg`

```
$("#fs-trans").val("'<?php echo $fee->transport_chg; ?>'");
```